# mvc entity framework update field incrementing this value

Tags: entity-framework, auto-increment

Im a doing an `MVC` with `Entity Framework` App.

I have to update a unique field, autoincrementing this value in 1.

```html
  ConnectionEntities _db;
 
 public void AddingVisits(long upload_id)
        {
            var upload = new Uploads() { Upload_id = upload_id, CantVisits = CantVisits + 1 };
            _db.Uploads.Attach(upload);
            _db.Entry(upload).Property(x => x.CantVisits).IsModified = true;
            _db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Where Upload is the `Entity`, Upload_id is the indentity field and I need to increment `CantVisits` field, adding 1 to this current value.

This example get me an error in line

> CantVisits = CantVisits

I do not what is this current value, and I want to avoid doing a `select` to get this value.

It is that posible?

Comment: autoincrementing means you do not set the value it is set automatically so I'm a little confused by what you asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that column is not identity and you just want to add one to that property then you could do this:

```
var upload = new Uploads() { Upload_id = upload_id };
//Attach the existing entity to the context
_db.Uploads.Attach(upload);
// due to you set a property, the EF change tracker will detect your entity was modified, if you haven't disabled it
upload.CantVisits+=1;
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Or changing the entity state to `Modified`:

```
var upload = new Uploads() { Upload_id = upload_id };
// due to you set a property the entity change tracker will detect your entity was modified, if you haven't disabled it
upload.CantVisits+=1;
context.Entry(upload).State = EntityState.Modified; 

_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks... How can I manage in case upload.CantVisits is null ?

Comment: Well in that case change that line for: `upload.CantVisits=upload.CantVisits.HasValue?upload.CantVisits+1:1;`

Comment: Got an error "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.". I think it try to update all record instead of just the field.

Comment: What solution are you using, the first one or the second one?

Comment: Both.. the first gave an error "Validation failed for one or more entities." InnerException is null...

Comment: OK.. I add "_db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;" and it Works... but "upload.CantVisits.HasValue" always is false, even when canvisits is not null.

Comment: I never have set that property before. About `Cantvisits` property, what you said doesn't make sense to me, a nullable type if has a value, then HasValue is `true`. You can also use this other condition: `CantVisits!=null?...`

Comment: after I execute "var upload = new Uploads() { Upload_id = upload_id };" the only property that has value is upload.upload_id, all other properties are null. It does not go to database to bring current record.

Comment: Of course, see `upload` variable after you call `Attach`

Comment: is null before an after...I have set on the begining of the class " _db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;" Do not If is has something to do...It has nothing to do...

Comment: yes.. if I set " upload.CantVisits =100" it updates the field